# Python2 unable to pickle string

Tags: string, python-2.7, serialization, typeerror, pickle

[This](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/pickle.html#what-can-be-pickled-and-unpickled) link says that both normal and unicode strings can be pickled. But when I try following,

```
    def __del__ (self):
        with open(self._pkl, 'wb') as f:
            pickle.dump(dict(self._rec), f)
```

I'm getting

```
Exception TypeError: TypeError("can't pickle String objects",) in <bound method PickleOutput.__del__ of <pickleoutput.PickleOutput instance at 0x7f21989214d0>> ignored
```

error.

I'm unable to see what is wrong. Someone please help.